О слитном написании "вырвиглаз"

А разве вырвиглаз пишется слитно? Если по орфографическому словарю и ответам  Справочной службы, то да.

Русский орфографический словарь: вырвиглаз, другие формы не употр.

Но все же пишут раздельно,  например:
Одному не хватит яркости красок, а другой скажет, что это просто вырви 
глаз.  Анна Шехова, Синдром Золушки. Как избавиться от комплекса 
хорошей девочки, 2017

На этот раз мне хотелось посмотреть на дикую лесную яблоню, растущую на 
поляне среди берез. Летом и ранней осенью она вся была усыпана 
яблоками. Мелкие, продолговатые, с характерным бугорком около веточки, 
они были то, что называется в деревне «вырви глаз». Владимир 
Солоухин. Третья охота (1967) 


С другой стороны, часто ли вообще пишут? Устойчивое сочетание выглядит довольно "свирепым". Вырви глаз — ужас какой-то. Лучше уж сделать себе харакири (мнение из Сети).

И откуда вообще слитное написание словосочетания, прецедентов вроде бы нет. Сравнить: перекати-поле, не-тронь-меня, иван-да-марья. Хотя есть сорвиголова, но здесь нет падежного управления.


Вопросы: Почему нормирована слитная форма письма? Часто ли используется сочетание в современном языке?

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Глагол "напортачить": стиль речи, этимология, способ образования

Вот что рекомендуют правила русской орфографии и пунктуации (с изменениями, предложенными в 2000 году):

§78. Пишутся слитно: <...>
3. Склоняемые сложные имена существительные с глагольной первой частью на -и, например: горицвет, держидерево, держиморда, вертишейка, вертихвостка, скопидом, сорвиголова.
Изменения 2000 г.: Распространить слитное написание на все сложные существительные особого структурного типа — с первой частью, совпадающей с формой повелительного наклонения глагола. Писать слитно не только горицвет, держиморда, вертишейка, скопидом, сорвиголова, перекатиполе и т. п., но и грабьармия, гуляйгород (писавшиеся через дефис), неразлейвода (писавшееся раздельно, в три слова), вырвиглаз (слово, впервые орфографически регламентированное в академическом «Русском орфографическом словаре» 1999 г.).

[Проверила: в орфографическом словаре 1957 года под редакцией С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро (110 тысяч слов, печатный вариант) слово отсутствует.]
А статистика Нацкорпуса интересна:
вырвиглаз — 3 (первый пример — 2000 год, сразу после изменений);
вырви глаз — 12 (первый пример — 1926 год; С канупером табачок, по крепости — вырви глаз. Вл. А. Гиляровский. Москва и москвичи).
Нечасто встречается слово в литературе, совсем нечасто.
В быту же обычно употребляется в выражении "Квас — вырви глаз" и пишется до сих пор раздельно (см.: Николай Уваров. Энциклопедия народной мудрости: пословицы, поговорки, афоризмы, крылатые выражения, сравнения, устойчивые словосочетания, встречающиеся в русском живом языке во второй половине XX — начале XXI веков. 2009).
В нашей семье это слово использовала ещё моя бабушка (1909, Новгород), используем и мы.

Спасибо, Sharon, за интересный вопрос!

Спасибо вам за ответ!  Особенно было любопытно то, что словечко все-таки используется в обычной речи, но, может, не везде. Для меня оно было чисто книжным, ни от кого не слышала. // Теперь о правилах. Мне кажется, зря они старались все сделать одинаковым, к каждому слову нужен индивидуальный подход. Некоторые слова (склон. сущ.) воспринимаются как цельные, а другие  при слитном написании выглядят неестественно. Кстати, в словаре РАН обозначен дефис для двух слов: перекати-поле и гуляй-город.  "Неразлейвода" указано в знач. сказ, но в Нацкорпусе только 2 примера, все пишут раздельно.

Вырвиглаз - слитно, но грамматика почему-то не указана  (только: другие формы не употр.). // Еще раз большое спасибо за ответ.

Для справки — из ГРАММАТИКИ-80:


